# Iframe Question

Tags: integration, website-integration

Currently I'm trying to help a friend integrate his platform with Salesforce. Before, he could  use an iframe within on his side, but it seems Salesforce may have discontinued that feature.

I created a connected app , and appears the platforms can connect.

What I'm trying to figure out is, can I somehow now display the Salesforce front page information on the other app using iframes, or if that has changed is there another way.

Yeah feel free to call me an idiot, I'm new to this part of Salesforce, and I am having a tough time getting answers. :)

Comment: what do you mean by front page information?

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce login page cannot be iFramed, it is forbidden by X-Frame-Options on the SFDC server.

The answer to serving up context-specific information from another Salesforce instance is using a Canvas Signed Request. The Signed Request gives the app inside of the canvas running user information, so that you can display the right contextual content.

Answer (score 0):

As you're observing you definitely wont be able to iframe salesforce standard user interface into other sites, as not from same domain. If your friend wants to serve up a Salesforce page via iframe within another web app, then they could consider using a custom sites page, and have the clickjack protection setting turned off for that specific site. Should be ok from there.

Comment: This is actually not true, it's possible to serve up Visualforce pages if you're authenticated into that other instance. It's the authentication piece that is difficult via the iframe.

Comment: SO if I understand correctly, it would be possible to serve Visualforce pages over to the other platform? I'm trying to go Salesforce <> Infinite Media (that's the platform name), not Salesforce <> Salesforce.

Comment: you could, though keep in mind they're not connected in any way - you'd just be iframing in some content that is derived from a salesforce site and it is assuming a public site user context. @greenstork has provided feedback if you want connectivity and user context between the two sites.